# Python: How to combine specific columns from two different data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I am a new python user and would like to ask about does it possible to combine or merge the data frames that come from the different data frames but they have one column that has the same information?

```
Data 1             Data2
DocID GroupID      DocID  ClassID    
123     A12        123    X
123     A24        123    Y
124     A24        124    Z
124     C12        124    F
125     A12        125    G
```

I hope the result will be like this

```
Results
            DocID  123 124 125
Group_ID Class_ID
  A12      X        1   0   0
  A24      Y        1   0   0
  A24      Z        0   1   0
  C12      F        0   0   1
  A12      G        0   0   1
```

Thank you for helping in advance T___T

Comment: If you've got df1 and df2 loaded... then you can try: `df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='DocID')`? Then reshape?

Comment: thank you for your help, i found the solution : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To merge the datasets you can concatenate them after setting `DocID` as the index (if not yet):

```
>>> merged = pd.concat((df1.set_index('DocID'), df2.set_index('DocID')), axis=1)
>>> print(merged)

      GroupID ClassID
DocID
123       A12       X
123       A24       Y
124       A24       Z
124       C12       F
125       A12       G
```

After this, to mimic your desired result, you'll need to get the dummies for the index. The simples one is to just get them with `pd.get_dummies` after resetting the index:

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(merged.reset_index(), columns=['DocID'])

      GroupID ClassID  DocID_123  DocID_124  DocID_125
0     A12       X          1          0          0
1     A24       Y          1          0          0
2     A24       Z          0          1          0
3     C12       F          0          1          0
4     A12       G          0          0          1
```

However, if you really need the multiindex dummies, you'll need to dummify the index and then construct a multiindex columns out of it and concatenate them with the `merged` dataframe.